# How do I copy and paste the content inside quotes from one place to another?

Tags: regular-expression, substitute

Lets say I have a buffer with the following content:

```
<property name="sfgiusfgsnffgdsb" value="arbitraryvalue1"/>
<property name="sfsergggsnfgdfgs" value="arbitraryvalue2"/>
<property name="sfggdsssgdshsdhg" value="arbitraryvalue3"/>
<property name="sfgisdfggngsdfgf" value="arbitraryvalue4"/>
<property name="sfgsdgfggnsfgsgf" value="arbitraryvalue5"/>
<property name="sfgfgsdffskghjkf" value="arbitraryvalue6"/>
```

and I want the following result

```
<property name="arbitraryvalue1" value="arbitraryvalue1"/>
<property name="arbitraryvalue2" value="arbitraryvalue2"/>
<property name="arbitraryvalue3" value="arbitraryvalue3"/>
<property name="arbitraryvalue4" value="arbitraryvalue4"/>
<property name="arbitraryvalue5" value="arbitraryvalue5"/>
<property name="arbitraryvalue6" value="arbitraryvalue6"/>
```

I realize I can do this with a macro or defining a function, but how can it be done with a just a command? `:what_to_put_here`

Comment: Incidentally, this can be also be performed by copying and pasting in blockwise visual mode.

Comment: Also, this was crossposted here: https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/wdttoz/how_do_i_copy_and_paste_the_content_inside_quotes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using [`:normal`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal)

You can do this by executing normal mode editing commands with [`:normal`](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Anormal):

```
:%norm!3f"yi"0vi"p
```

### How it works

```
:%norm!3f"yi"0vi"p
 %                   # On every line,
  norm!              # Run the commands:
       3f"           # Move to the third quote mark on the line,
          yi"        # Yank the contents of the quoted string,
             0       # Move back to the start of the line,
              vi"    # Select inside the first quoted string on the line, and
                 p   # Paste the yanked string
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%s/\v".*"(.*)(".*")/\2\1\2
```